# Netbook Remix [EasyPeasy]: How to add a Mozilla Prism to Favorites

Tags: file-manager

I'm setting up a old laptop with EasyPeasy, the only Linux distro I could get to install on it.  I want to put a Prism in the favorites that will bring up a web site we use frequently. I created the Prism, and its icon is in the desktop folder, but that does nothing as the desktop is hidden. I can navigate to the folder and launch it, but the point of creating it is easy access.

How do I get the launcher to the favorites, so that as soon as the machine is booted up the user sees it right in front of them?

Comment: Really? *This* was migrated *from* AskUbuntu? Is it because EasyPeasy != Ubuntu? Just curious what the justification for the migration was..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out a hack.  Since the launchers that come with EasyPeasy can be right clicked and then added to Favorites; I did that with one of them.  Then I ran gconf-editor and in it navigated to /apps/netbook-launcher/favorites.  I found the folder containing the launcher I just added, double clicked on its key named desktop_file and changed its value to point to my Prism desktop file.  I then logged off and back on again and eureka my prism launcher was not only showing up in Favorites it is also working perfectly.

Comment: Thank you for posting the solution that you found instead of leaving the question open :)